# Session / Transaction problems with Spring/Hibernate/HSQLDB combo

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

for training purposes I am currently rewriting my application to use a combination of Spring and Hibernate to access my local HSQLDB instead of just doing it via JDBC alone.

I think that I got most of it working and when I execute a few methods on my main method for testing purposes everything seems to work fine. However, once I want to enable the transaction handling via @Transactional the whole thing stops working, telling me that there is no connection present.

I already tried a few solutions given in similar question here on stackoverflow, but none did the trick for me.

First of all the full stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/ACkp7Ysj

And here are my classes and config files:

Datasource Config:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

  <bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

  <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\\dev\\source\\productionDB\\productionDB;shutdown=true" />
  <property name="username" value="admin" />
  <property name="password" value="admin" />
  </bean>   

  <bean id="sessionFactory" 
   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="exercise.java.basics.storage" />

  <property name="mappingLocations">
  <list>
  <value>classpath:hibernate/Warehouse.hbm.xml</value>

  </list>
  </property>

  <property name="hibernateProperties">
     <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
     </props>
  </property>

 </bean>

  <bean id="txManager" 
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" 
class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

   </beans>
```

DAO Config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="warehouseDAO" class="exercise.java.basics.storage.WarehouseDAOImpl">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>

</bean>

</beans>
```

Module Config:

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<import resource="database/Spring-Datasource.xml" />
<import resource="warehouse/Spring-Warehouse.xml" />

</beans>
```

Hibernate Mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="exercise.java.basics.storage.WarehouseNew" table="WAREHOUSE">
    <id name="product_ID" type="integer">
        <column name="product_ID"  not-null="true"/>
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="product_name" type="string">
        <column name="product_name" length="100"/>
    </property>
    <property name="product_count" type="integer">
        <column name="product_count"/>
    </property>
 </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

DAO Pattern:

```
public interface WarehouseDAO {

public void initializeWarehouse();

public void storeProducts( final Product product, final int count );

public void removeProducts( final Product product, final int count );

public void updateStock();

}
```

DAO Implementation:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public class WarehouseDAOImpl implements WarehouseDAO {

private DataSource     dataSource;

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setDataSource( final DataSource dataSource ) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public void setSessionFactory( final SessionFactory sessionFactory ) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public void initializeWarehouse() {

    String initProductsSQL = "INSERT INTO WAREHOUSE(product_name, product_count) VALUES  (?, 0)";

    Connection conn = null;

    try {

        conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection( this.dataSource );

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( initProductsSQL );
        ps.setString( 1, String.valueOf( Product.NAIL ) );
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.setString( 1, String.valueOf( Product.SCREW ) );
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.setString( 1, String.valueOf( Product.FINALPRODUCT ) );
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ps.close();

    } catch ( SQLException e ) {
        throw new RuntimeException( e );

    } finally {
        if ( conn != null ) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch ( SQLException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

public void storeProducts( final Product product, final int count ) {

    String updateProductCountSQL = "UPDATE WAREHOUSE SET product_count = product_count + " + count
            + " WHERE product_name = '" + product + "'";

    Connection conn = null;

    try {

        conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection( this.dataSource );

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute( updateProductCountSQL );
        stmt.close();

    } catch ( SQLException e ) {
        throw new RuntimeException( e );

    } finally {
        if ( conn != null ) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch ( SQLException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

public void removeProducts( final Product product, final int count ) {

    String updateProductCountSQL = "UPDATE WAREHOUSE SET product_count = product_count - " + count
            + " WHERE product_name = '" + product + "'";

    Connection conn = null;

    try {

        conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection( this.dataSource );

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute( updateProductCountSQL );
        stmt.close();

    } catch ( SQLException e ) {
        throw new RuntimeException( e );

    } finally {
        if ( conn != null ) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch ( SQLException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

public void updateStock() {

    String getUpdatedStocksSQL = "SELECT * FROM WAREHOUSE WHERE product_name = ? ;";

    Connection conn = null;

    try {

        conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection( this.dataSource );

        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement( getUpdatedStocksSQL );

        WarehouseNew warehouse = exercise.java.basics.storage.WarehouseNew.getInstance();

        ps.setString( 1, String.valueOf( Product.NAIL ) );
        ResultSet rsNail = ps.executeQuery();
        ps.setString( 1, String.valueOf( Product.SCREW ) );
        ResultSet rsScrew = ps.executeQuery();
        ps.setString( 1, String.valueOf( Product.FINALPRODUCT ) );
        ResultSet rsFinalProduct = ps.executeQuery();

        rsNail.next();
        rsScrew.next();
        rsFinalProduct.next();

        warehouse.setNailCount( rsNail.getString( 3 ) );
        warehouse.setScrewCount( rsNail.getString( 3 ) );
        warehouse.setFinalProductCount( rsNail.getString( 3 ) );

        //Debug
        System.out.println( rsNail.getInt( 3 ) );
        System.out.println( rsScrew.getInt( 3 ) );
        System.out.println( rsFinalProduct.getInt( 3 ) );

        rsNail.close();
        rsScrew.close();
        rsFinalProduct.close();
        ps.close();

    } catch ( SQLException e ) {
        throw new RuntimeException( e );
    } finally {
        if ( conn != null ) {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch ( SQLException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

public static void main( final String[] args ) {

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext( "Spring-Module.xml" );

    WarehouseDAO warehouseDAO = (WarehouseDAO) context.getBean( "warehouseDAO" );

    // warehouseDAO.initializeWarehouse();
    warehouseDAO.updateStock();

    warehouseDAO.storeProducts( Product.NAIL, 10 );
    warehouseDAO.storeProducts( Product.SCREW, 20 );
    warehouseDAO.storeProducts( Product.FINALPRODUCT, 30 );

    warehouseDAO.updateStock();

}
}
```

Model class:

```
public class WarehouseNew {

private int                          nailCount;
private int                          screwCount;
private int                          finalProductCount;
private int                          product_ID;

private String                       product_name;
private int                          product_count;

private static volatile WarehouseNew instance = null;

public static WarehouseNew getInstance() {
    if ( instance == null ) {
        synchronized ( WarehouseNew.class ) {
            if ( instance == null ) {
                instance = new WarehouseNew();
            }
        }
    }

    return instance;
}

/**
 * Constructor for ...
 */
private WarehouseNew() {

}

/**
 * @return the nailCount
 */
public int getNailCount() {
    return this.nailCount;
}

/**
 * @param string the nailCount to set
 */
public void setNailCount( final String string ) {
    this.nailCount = Integer.parseInt( string );
}

/**
 * @return the screwCount
 */
public int getScrewCount() {
    return this.screwCount;
}

/**
 * @param string the screwCount to set
 */
public void setScrewCount( final String string ) {
    this.screwCount = Integer.parseInt( string );
}

/**
 * @return the finalProductCount
 */
public int getFinalProductCount() {
    return this.finalProductCount;
}

/**
 * @param string the finalProductCount to set
 */
public void setFinalProductCount( final String string ) {
    this.finalProductCount = Integer.parseInt( string );
}

/**
 * @return the product_id
 */
public int getProduct_ID() {
    return this.product_ID;
}

/**
 * @param product_id the product_id to set
 */
public void setProduct_ID( final int product_ID ) {
    this.product_ID = product_ID;
}

/**
 * @return the product_name
 */
public String getProduct_name() {
    return this.product_name;
}

/**
 * @param product_name the product_name to set
 */
public void setProduct_name( final String product_name ) {
    this.product_name = product_name;
}

/**
 * @return the product_count
 */
public int getProduct_count() {
    return this.product_count;
}

/**
 * @param product_count the product_count to set
 */
public void setProduct_count( final int product_count ) {
    this.product_count = product_count;
}

}
```

I hope someone can point me in the right direction. Spring framework and Hibernate are totally new to me and I just want it to work.

I don't really understand why the database access works when I am not using the @Transactional annonation, but then says that there is no connection present when using it... Just makes no sense to me.

best regards
daZza

**EDIT:** Changes based on the suggestion to use the sessionFactory. The error remains the same though.

```
// Experimental

    this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().doWork(

    new Work() {
        public void execute( final Connection connection ) throws SQLException {
            try {

                String getUpdatedStocksSQL = "SELECT * FROM WAREHOUSE WHERE product_name = ? ;";

                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement( getUpdatedStocksSQL );

                WarehouseNew warehouse = exercise.java.basics.storage.WarehouseNew.getInstance();

                ps.setString( 1, String.valueOf( Product.NAIL ) );
                ResultSet rsNail = ps.executeQuery();
                ps.setString( 1, String.valueOf( Product.SCREW ) );
                ResultSet rsScrew = ps.executeQuery();
                ps.setString( 1, String.valueOf( Product.FINALPRODUCT ) );
                ResultSet rsFinalProduct = ps.executeQuery();

                rsNail.next();
                rsScrew.next();
                rsFinalProduct.next();


                warehouse.setNailCount( rsNail.getString( 3 ) );
                warehouse.setScrewCount( rsNail.getString( 3 ) );
                warehouse.setFinalProductCount( rsNail.getString( 3 ) );

                System.out.println( rsNail.getInt( 3 ) );
                System.out.println( rsScrew.getInt( 3 ) );
                System.out.println( rsFinalProduct.getInt( 3 ) );

                rsNail.close();
                rsScrew.close();
                rsFinalProduct.close();
                ps.close();

            } catch ( SQLException e ) {
                throw new RuntimeException( e );
            } finally {
                if ( connection != null ) {
                    try {
                        connection.close();
                    } catch ( SQLException e ) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } );

    // !Experimental
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your jdbc driver URL is incorrect:

for HSQL it's

```
org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
```

you seem to have

```
<property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
```

which is a MS-SQL/Sybase driver class.

The main reason why your @Transaction annotation is failing at this point is that you are using a hibernate transaction manager (and would therefore only work when you start using the session factory).

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

For your old jdbc code to work you need to have something like this in place instead:

```
<bean id="txManager" 
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

An alternative way is to replace your DataSourceUtils.getConnection( this.dataSource with sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().connection(). This is actually [deprectated](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#connection%28%29) so you'd be better off using [sessionFactory.getCurrentSession.doWork()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#doWork%28org.hibernate.jdbc.Work%29) instead.

Comment: Thanks, will try to make changes based on that. I want to work with Hibernate, so I guess I'll try the sessionFactory approach. A question though, why am I not using the sessionFactory right now? As far as I understood, I injected the sessionFactory to my DAO via a setter injection. So I should be using it already?

Comment: According to your code, when you acquire your database connection, it's done via `conn = DataSourceUtils.getConnection( this.dataSource );`. This get's the connection via the datasource, not the SessionFactory

Comment: Ah ok. I thought that with @AutoWire and the setter injection spring handles everything itself. Didn't know that session = connection. I tried implementing your suggestion, but keep getting the same error message. For the code see my original post. What I find astonishing though is that the sysos actually print the correct values to the console and only after that's done the error occurs.

Comment: Had a look at the experimental code, I do not think that you need to close the database connection at the end. My understanding of this is that hibernate passes the connection as a parameter, so it would manage the connection for you in terms of opening and closing.

And the exception `Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: connection exception: connection does not exist` could be because that the connection was closed prematurely (by that code at the end), but that's just me trying to reason between the exception and the code :)